Angular momentum of an object performing rotational and transitional motion
If we take an example of a ring which is performing combined translational and rotational motion, being $v$ the velocity of its COM and $\omega$ the angular velocity. Consider there is no external torque. Then while calculating its  angular momentum at a specific instance I found that it is being calculated by $I\omega+mvr$. I understood $I\omega$, but how is the linear momentum due to translational motion affecting its angular momentum??

Do you know the definition of angular momentum? why do you find the first term understandable and the second one not?

I know the definition of angular momentum but how can a linear velocity of com cause a angular momentum and If I am missing something basic from the definition then correct me.

For a particle, the definition is $\vec L=\vec R \times \vec p$, where x is the cross product.
If the motion is rectilinear and does not pass through the origin, this can be expressed, for the magnitudes as  $ L=  R p \sin \theta =rmv$, where r is the perpendicular distance to the straight line of motion.
For a purely rotating rigid object, you can calculate the total angular momentum in a reference frame in which the axis of rotation is at the center, by adding that of each individual point (perform an integral), and then is when you get the result $L=I\omega$.
If the object is both rotating and translating, then you can prove you need to add both, the rotation component, and the translation component of the center of mass. This comes from decomposing the velocity of each point in the object into purely rotating and purely translating components.

If I assume com as my refrence frame ??

In that reference system both $r=0$ and $v=0$ and so  the second term is zero.
